# Custom Context Menu on everything except "input" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I want to add custom context menu with jQuery for the whole body of the page, except the textfields. How can I do that?
I have tried that code:

```
$('body:not(input)').bind('contextmenu', function(){
    /*code*/
});
```

Comment: Start by trying something, then come back when it fails

Comment: And don't forget to google [Custom Context Menu on everything except “input” in jQuery](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Custom+Context+Menu+on+everything+except+“input”+in+jQuery)

Comment: I posted the code I've tried.

Comment: You need blocked right mouse click and show <div> with you custom contextmenu. I think you can just find jQuery plugin.

By the way: http://goo.gl/h0jQyl

Answer (score 2):

Check the `srcElement` before plugin executions. If it's not an input element, do trigger the contextmenu plugin:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.srcElement).is(":input")) { // if it's not an input element...
        $(this).triggerTheContextMenuPlugin();
    }
});
```

Comment: `e.target` and `e.srcElement` return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Use an event listener on the `document` and check if it was initiated by an **input** element.

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
        console.log("context menu triggered");
    }
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/wuju8/)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Salman's solution.

You can **stop the event propagation** in all input elements, with the `e.stopPropagation()` function. In doing so, you keep the default behavior of the `inputs` elements:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) {
        alert("Context menu triggered, preventing default");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("input").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/luclethannois/qxbz60wm/)